# Подмена содержимого страницы на своем сайте

Tags: html, css, nginx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что и можно использовать, чтобы менять содержимое странички в зависимости от IP_адреса пользователя? Есть NGINX, страничка - простой HTML.

Подмена самой странички - мне не подходит, нужно менять содержимое при открытии в зависимости от IP (буквально для одной 24 маски нужно другое содержимое)

Comment: Скорее всего необходимо реализовать это средствами PHP, написав метод проверки вхождения IP. Такая реализация подходит под ваши ограничения?

Comment: Если юзеру нужно отдавать только необходимые данные, а не все сразу со скрытием - только замена всей странички.

Comment: @mepihindeveloper, да, PHP поставить вроде можно. Т.е. мы определяем IP-адрес, в зависимости от него показываем одно содержимое страницы или другое?

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, можно и скрывать, ключевой момент - я могу через шлюз передать только конкретный файл (одну html страницу) с содержимым, в текущей конфигурации нельзя менять страницу - шлюз так настроен, что вторую страницу не отобразит..